# EmberJS: Bind input value to Controller property and run filter on change

Tags: javascript, binding, ember.js, filter

I'm trying to bind a input's value to it's controller's property to keep it updated when the property changes. When the input value has changed, I then need to fire a filter method.

I found some examples, but I'm either doing something wrong or they no longer apply as they are a few months old and Ember has gone through some changes.

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oTiKiDI/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were able to manipulate the `this.inputDate` property directly, as you're doing in your jsbin, I believe it wouldn't properly fire any observers when you change the value. So rather than manipulating `this.inputDate.anything`, you should `this.set('inputDate', [whatever])`.

A `Date().getDate()` returns just the day of the month, not any usable proxy to a Date object, and adding `1` to that value will not add one day to your `Date()`. I prefer to use http://momentjs.com/ to manipulate dates painlessly and semantically.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oKehAYE/3/edit works, and has `filterDate` pulled out of the actions hash and turned into an observer. If you uncomment the `alert()` line it will do something when the `inputDate` changes. It probably doesn't work ideally, since when the page initially renders you have a `Date` object, and then once you change it you have a `Moment`—you might as well initialize `inputDate` with `moment(new Date)`—but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.